# How to remove memory allocated by const char* iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, memory-leaks, char, constants

How can I remove memory allocated by const char* arrayname in iOS 7.
here is my code

```
 const char *bytes = [encodedString UTF8String];
```

Now I want to release `bytes` with ARC enabled. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not release memory pointed by `bytes` pointer directly as it is managed by `encodedString` object. To free that memory get rid of all strong references to encodedString and memory should get released

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything to ensure it will be released eventually.  Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String):

> The returned C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you called this method.

In other words, you don't know the lifetime of the array, but you know it may not live long and it will be freed automatically.